# Festival- how to make speech synthesis read numbers like "1325.25" as "one three two five point two five"?

Tags: libreoffice, text-to-speech, festival

I am using Ubuntu 15.10. In Libreoffice calc, I am using an extension "[read text](https://sites.google.com/site/readtextextension/)" to read numbers using Festival speech synthesis.

How to set up Festival speech synthesis to read numbers like "1325.25"  as "one three two five point two five" instead of  one thousand three hundred twenty-five point two five?. Is there any setting in Festival for that?

If it is not possible in Festival, is there any other speech synthesis software which can do it?

( I tried converting the number to text, but then the point is read by Festival as 'dot'.)